# What is the safest way, broadly supported across browsers, to create prototype chains?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

So I'm still learning JavaScript, and I'm working with prototypes right now. The lesson I just completed showed me how to use `__proto__` to create prototype inheritance chains. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
function Person(firstName,lastName,dob){
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.dob = new Date(dob);
}
Person.prototype = {
  constructor: Person,
  getFullName: function(){
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  },
  getAge: function(){
    var ageDiff = Date.now() - this.dob;
    var ageDiffDate = new Date(ageDiff);
    return Math.abs(ageDiffDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
  }
}

function Employee(firstName,lastName,dob,position,dept){
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.dob = new Date(dob);
  this.position = position;
  this.dept = dept;
  this.isFired = false;
}
Employee.prototype = {
  constructor: Employee,
  __proto__: Person.prototype,
  doWork: function(){
    console.log(this.getFullName() + " is doing work");
  }
}

function Manager(firstName,lastName,dob,dept){
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.dob = new Date(dob);
  this.position = "Manager";
  this.dept = dept;
}
Manager.prototype = {
  constructor: Manager,
  __proto__: Employee.prototype,
  fireEmployee: function(emp){
    emp.isFired = true;
    console.log(this.getFullName() + " has fired " + emp.getFullName());
  }
}

var per = new Person("Bob","Saget","1990-02-05");
var emp = new Employee("Jane","Doe","1980-05-02","Clerk","Sales");
var mgr = new Manager("Jim","Smith","1970-09-10","Sales");
```

`Employee` inherits from `Person.prototype`, and `Manager` inherits from `Employee.prototype`. Nice and simple.

However, I've read that the `__proto__` property isn't guaranteed across all web browsers, since ES6 hasn't been widely adopted yet. I've been scanning the internet, trying to find a clear explanation of what to do instead, and I'm getting a little bit lost.

What is the safe, broadly supported way of setting prototype inheritance chains in ES5, other than using `__proto__`?

Comment: `__proto__` is officially deprecated in ES6.

Comment: Please read [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/243450) before attempting to ask more questions that are opinion based that invite argumentative discussion because they do not have a single agreed upon answer.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way is using **standard** ES5 and above approaches.

```
function A() {}

function B() {}
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto):

> The use of __proto__ is controversial, and has been discouraged. It was never originally included in the EcmaScript language spec, but modern browsers decided to implement it anyway. Only recently, the __proto__ property has been standardized in the ECMAScript 6 language specification for web browsers to ensure compatibility, so will be supported into the future. It is deprecated in favor of [Object.getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)/[Reflect.getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/getPrototypeOf) and [Object.setPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf)/[Reflect.setPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/setPrototypeOf) (though still, setting the [[Prototype]] of an object is a slow operation that should be avoided if performance is a concern).

Please also consider the warning concerning performance

> **Warning**: Changing the [[Prototype]] of an object is, by the nature of how modern JavaScript engines optimize property accesses, a very slow operation, in every browser and JavaScript engine. (...)

If you don't mind the performance implications or just want to experiment with prototypes, the article [Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) gives an excellent introduction on how the prototype chain in JS works. I'll quote the part that mentions the three different ways to create custom prototype chains here:

### With a constructor

A "constructor" in JavaScript is "just" a function that happens to be called with the [new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

```js
function Graph() {
  this.vertices = [];
  this.edges = [];
}

Graph.prototype = {
  addVertex: function(v){
    this.vertices.push(v);
  }
};

var g = new Graph();

console.log("g:", Object.keys(g))
console.log("g.prototype:", Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(g)))
```

### With `Object.create`

ECMAScript 5 introduced a new method: Object.create(). Calling this method creates a new object. The prototype of this object is the first argument of the function:

```js
var a = {a: 1}; 
// a ---> Object.prototype ---> null

var b = Object.create(a);
// b ---> a ---> Object.prototype ---> null
console.log(b.a); // 1 (inherited)

var c = Object.create(b);
// c ---> b ---> a ---> Object.prototype ---> null

var d = Object.create(null);
// d ---> null
console.log(d.hasOwnProperty); 
// undefined, because d doesn't inherit from Object.prototype
```

### With the `class` keyword

ECMAScript 6 introduced a new set of keywords implementing classes. Although these constructs look like those familiar to developers of class-based languages, they are not the same. JavaScript remains prototype-based. The new keywords include class, constructor, static, extends, and super.

```js
"use strict";

class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}

class Square extends Polygon {
  constructor(sideLength) {
    super(sideLength, sideLength);
  }
  get area() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
  set sideLength(newLength) {
    this.height = newLength;
    this.width = newLength;
  }
}

var square = new Square(2);
```

### Conclusion

I'd agree with Matias' answer and recommend using `Object.create`, because it does not hide the prototypal nature of JavaScript - in contrast to constructors or ES6 classes.

Comment: Good answer! I still think what would be the use case of changing a given object prototype. If you already define the prototype of a new object using `Object.create`, it seems like changing it later might be a design smell :/

Comment: Thanks! I also don't see why one would change an object's prototype after its creation.

Comment: Maybe I've found one! What if you want to don't force callers of some function to pass an object of a given prototype, but they just give an object literal or something created from `Object.create(null)`, and the function itself chains the desired prototype in order to simplify how to work with the whole function?